# Regular expression for mobile number validation

Tags: java, regex

Hi I need to validate mobile number based on the following criteria

- minimum 8 numbers
- allowed characters only `=` `+`, `space`

So I have tried using the following regular expression

```
([0-9]\\s*){8}
```

But its not working. Can any one help me?

Comment: What's better is to strip all non-digits and *then* validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off (if you really want to follow these criteria):

```
^[=+\s]*(?:[0-9][=+\s]*){8,}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
[=+\s]*  # Optionally match =, + or whitespace
(?:      # Start of group:
 [0-9]   # Match a digit
 [=+\s]* # Optionally match =, + or whitespace
){8,}    # Repeat at least 8 times
$        # End of string
```

Don't forget to double the backslashes in a Java string:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[=+\\s]*(?:[0-9][=+\\s]*){8,}$");
```

But of course these rules also permit matches like `++++0+0===0=+0+000+0+0+0+0+++`...

Comment: This is exact one i need Thanx :)